# Multiple items for a single coordinate in GeoJSON

Tags: json, leaflet, mapbox, geojson

I've set up a rest API that is supplying geojson data from a database. The issue is each coordinate could/does have multiple items associated to it.

Currently troubleshooting the application's javascript file to load, and plot - but looking for feedback on best practice. Any information is appreciated. Thanks!

```js
var foo = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "item": "A",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          90,
          135
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "item": "B",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          90,
          135
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "item": "C",
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
          90,
          135
        ]
      }
    },
...
```

Comment: So what is the question? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Should preface this with I'm fairly new to JS. But looking to display multiple items per a single coordinate - if this is even possible. Ultimately wanting to create a dashboard to display the map, but also wanting to list out all items associated to a click event on a given coordinate.

Comment: You can use marker clusters to achieve that. Your question is exactly the same with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22173475/4929531)

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the feedback. This will display children in 'spiral' format.